# Daisy-chained ListCollectionView not reflecting changes to filter in source collection

Tags: apache-flex, listcollectionview

ListCollectionView is often promoted as a great way to daisy-chain different views of the same data.  You have some source collection and then use ListCollectionView + filterFunction to wrap the source data and present a subset of that source collection.  When the source collection changes (either adds or removals), the chained LCV gets updated automatically.  However, if the filterFunction for the *source collection* changes, it does not appear to propagate to the chained LCV:

```
ArrayCollection source = new ArrayCollection(new Array({name: 'Matt'}, {name: 'John'}, {name: 'Zach'}));
ListCollectionView justMatts = new ListCollectionView(source);
justMatts.filterFunction(function(obj: Object):Boolean { obj.name == 'Matt' });
justMatts.refresh();
```

If I add a new Matt object to `source`, `justMatts` will pick up that change and rerun its filter as expected.

However, if I add a filter to `source` to exclude Matt objects, `justMatts` doesn't pick up that change to the source's filter:

```
source.filterFunction(function(obj: Object):Boolean { obj.name != 'Matt' });
source.refresh();
```

At this point, I would expect justMatts to receive a `CollectionChangeEvent` and rerun its filter.  Since all Matts have been filtered out of the `source` object, `justMatts` would be empty as well.  However if you look in `ListCollectionView` code, they don't handle a `CollectionEventKind.REFRESH` which is what gets fired when `source` gets a new filter applied.  Am I doing something wrong here (using wrong class, etc) or does nothing in Flex support the changes to `source` filter.

I can get this working as I expect it to by manually dispatching a `CollectionEventKind.RESET` on `source`, but I was hoping to not have to subclass anything.

Comment: ArrayCollection subclasses ListCollectionView.  You may find that you can get this to work as you expect if you can get an AC to wrap another AC instead of an Array.

Comment: Doesn't work that way AFAIK.  AC requires an Array as you said.  You can get a *snapshot* of the filtered AC by calling AC#toArray, but that won't receive updates after the snapshot.

Comment: You might be able to set the List property on a new AC

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect it to work like that at all.  I would expect that the source of both the ArrayCollection (which is a LisCollectionView) and the explict ListCollectionView to be identical, with their filters operating independently.

However, if you poke around in the source code for these two Classes, you may well find that either filtering the AC doesn't dispatch a CollectionChange event (doubtful, since it requires refresh), or LCV doesn't listen for the event and update.

If you apply the filter to the list first and THEN make the ListCollectionView, do you see the results you expect? If not, then I think you've misread how this is supposed to work.  If you do, then I have ;-)

Comment: If you apply the filter to the source first and then create the LCV (as you say), the LCV is operating on the *filtered source*, not the original source.  For example, if I filtered the source with a filterFunction that always returned false, the chained collection would always be empty as well.  This whole blog article (http://graemeharker.blogspot.com/2009/04/implementing-presentation-model-in-flex.html) is based on the premise that you can chain these filters.

Comment: Then you probably need to poke around inside LCV and see why it's not reacting to the collection change event.  Note that in the blog post you're pointing to, there _is_ no daisy chaining in the way you're trying to do it. The underlying AC is left alone, and the sorts and filters are applied to the LCV's based on it.